# How do you make an errorbar plot in matplotlib using linestyle=None in rcParams?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting errorbar plots, matplotlib is not following the rcParams of no linestyle.  Instead, it's plotting all of the points connected with a line.  Here's a minimum working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lines = {'linestyle': 'None'}
plt.rc('lines', **lines)

plt.errorbar((0, 1), (1, 0), yerr=(0.1, 0.1), marker='o')

plt.savefig('test.pdf')
plt.delaxes()
```

[image]

Is the only solution to explicitly set `linestyle='None'` when calling `pyplot.errorbar()`?

Comment: An annoying default matplotlib. Errorbar implies that data want to be plotted; and data are usually discrete and should not be connected with a line.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a "bug" in older versions of `matplotlib` (and has been [fixed](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3103/files) for the 1.4 series).  The issue is that in `Axes.errorbar` there is a default value of `'-'` for `fmt`, which is then passed to the call to `plot` which is used to draw the markers and line.  Because a format string is passed into `plot` in never looks at the default value in `rcparams`.

You can also pass in `fmt = ''`

```
eb = plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=.1, fmt='', color='b')
```

which will cause the `rcParam['lines.linestlye']` value to be respected.  I have submitted a [PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2738)to implement this.

Another work around for this is to make the errorbar in two steps:

```
l0, = plt.plot(x,y, marker='o', color='b')
eb = plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=.1, fmt=None, color='b')
```

This is an annoying design decision, but changing it would be a major api break.  Please open an issue on github about this.

errorbar [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar).

As a side note, it looks like the call signature was last changed in 2007, and that was to make errorbars not default to blue.

Comment: Thanks, I've opened an issue: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2366

Comment: `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning`: Use of `None` object as fmt keyword argument to suppress plotting of data values is deprecated since 1.4; use the string `"none"` instead.

Comment: The argument `fmt=''` still plots the connecting line so it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @strpeter I have the same problem, I had to specify some marker at least, e.g. `fmt='.'`, then the line was finally gone, and I needed a marker anyway.

Comment: Yes, indeed I know but it's supposed to work without any further argument as well if I understood it correctly. Sometimes having an additional marker is just confusing.

Comment: This did not work, so I also had to use a marker. I used `fmt=','` because `fmt='.'` is still visible behind the error bars.

Answer (score 9):

Using: `fmt=''` indeed doesn't work. One needs to put something that is not an empty string.
As mentioned by @strpeter, a dot or any other marker would work.
Examples:
`fmt='.'`
`fmt=' '`
`fmt='o'`

Answer (score 3):

Or use an empty linestyle:

```
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=.1, fmt=None, color='b', linestyle='')
```

This works for me in matplotlib version 3.3.3